# Как дописать скрипт что бы можно было вызывать проверку в шаблоне. Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть скрипт. Нужно немного его переделать.
Суть скрипта проверять есть ли в массиве избранных сервис на который нажимает пользователь. Добавление\удаление из избранного.

```
$scope.manageFavorService = function (serviceId) {
     var data = {};//sending an empty array to get response
     getService = serviceId;

     PortalApi.getFavorServices(data)//get an array with all favorites services
     .then(function(data) {
         function isFavorite(id)//looking if there already serviceId exist
         {
             return data.filter(function(data)
                 { return data.service_id== id});
         }

         var isFavorite = isFavorite(getService),
             data = {serviceId:serviceId};

         if (isFavorite.length == 0) {//add favorite if in answer we got empty array
             PortalApi.addFavorServices(data);
         }
         else {//del favorite if in answer we got array with our service
             PortalApi.delFavorServices(data);
         }
     });
 };
```

PortalApi.getFavorServices

```
getFavorServices: function(data) {
                    var defer = $q.defer();

                    watchResponse(function() {
                        return services.one('receivers').one('getFavorServices').post('', {
                            data: data
                        });
                    }, function(response) {
                        return defer.resolve(response);
                    }, function(reason) {
                        return defer.reject(reason);
                    });

                    return defer.promise;
                },
```

Не могу понять как его дописать что бы можно было вызывать проверку isFavorite в коде html что бы к примеру сменять класс кнопки. проект на angularjs

хочу там делать проверку

```
ng-class="{'glyphicon-heart' : isFavorite , 'glyphicon-heart-empty' : !isFavorite }"
```

в целом кнопка

```
<button ng-if="auth.user" ng-click="manageFavorService(service.id)"  class="fa favorite-service" ng-class="{'fa-star' : isFavorite , 'fa-star-o' : !isFavorite }" uib-tooltip="{{!isFavorite ? 'SERVICES.FAVORITES.ADDTO' : 'SERVICES.FAVORITES.DELFROM' | translate}}" tooltip-placement="left"></button>
```

Comment: добавляй реализацию метода: `PortalApi.getFavorServices`

Comment: вот так `var isFavorite = isFavorite` лучше не делать

Comment: _как его дописать что бы можно было вызывать проверку isFavorite в коде html_ - никак, чтобы был доступ в разметке, переменная должна быть внутри $scope, а у тебя сейчас - локальная переменная

Comment: ну а если сделать так
$scope.manageFavorService = function ($scope, serviceId) {

не ужели не возможно допилить как то?

Comment: сработал такой вариант
ng-class="isFavorite ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'"

$scope.isFavorite = getFavorList(getService),

но при клике меняет всем элементам на странице и только 1 раз. почему?

Comment: если ты сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос, напиши ответ, с подробным описанием как решил проблему, либо просто удали вопрос

Comment: _но при клике меняет всем элементам на странице_ - очевидно потому, что ты присваиваешь только одну переменную. В принципе у тебя в вопросе ничего и нет про то, что их может быть много

Comment: не понимаю. а сколько переменных то должно быть? как этого избежать?

Comment: вот как  кнопка расположена

<li ng-repeat="service in services" title="{{service.name}}">
                               
 <button ng-if="auth.user" ng-click="manageFavorService(service.id)"  class="fa favorite-service" ng-class="isFavorite ? 'fa-star' : 'fa-star-o'></button>

Comment: добавил в вопросе, описаниеPortalApi.getFavorServices

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53673/discussion-between-grundy-and-maxim-m).